# Applying various filters to ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, listbox, delegates

I have a `ListBox` filled with several (up to hundreds) of `Phonecall` objects. I want to be able to filter them based on various criteria, and that criteria is decided by the user by various check boxes in the form. The ideal situation would be that the user could apply filters to check the time the call was made at, how long the call lasted, and other things. Currently, they can only apply one filter at a time. I tried doing this at first:

```
static int MaxDuration = 15;

Predicate<object> timeFilter = (object item) =>
{
    Phonecall p = item as Phonecall;
    return p.IsBadCall == true; //Decided by method in class definition
};

Predicate<object> durationFilter = (object item) =>
{
    Phonecall p = item as Phonecall;
    return p.Duration > MaxDuration;
};

...

private void applyFiltBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (timeFilterChkB.IsChecked == true)
        CallList.Items.Filter = timeFilter;
    if (durFilterChkB.IsChecked == true) 
        CallList.Items.Filter = durationFilter; //Overrides previous filter
}
```

After seeing that the above didn't work when both boxes were selected, I tried doing the following:

```
CallList.Items.Filter = (o) =>
        {
            Phonecall pc = o as Phonecall;
            if (timeFilterChkB.IsChecked == true && durFilterChkB.IsChecked == false)
                return pc.IsBadCall == true;
            else if (timeFilterChkB.IsChecked == false && durFilterChkB.IsChecked == true)
                return pc.Duration > MaxDuration;
            else if (timeFilterChkB.IsChecked == true && durFilterChkB.IsChecked == true)
                return pc.IsBadCall == true && pc.Duration > MaxDuration;
            else
                return true; //No filter is applied
        };
```

It works, but looks ugly and will only grow to be a large, hard-to-read "if-else" tree (as there are several other properties that will need to be filtered over time - about 10, and I'd rather not have to hard-code all the possible check box options).

In short, is there a better way to combine various predicates into a single filter or apply more than one filter at a time, so that only items that fit show  in the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also combine your two approaches.  For the first part, store a list of predicates instead of assigning immediately:

```
var predicates = new List<Predicate<object>>();
if (timeFilterChkB.IsChecked == true)
    predicates.Add(timeFilter);
if (durFilterChkB.IsChecked == true) 
    predicates.Add(durationFilter);
```

And for the second part, apply all the predicates:

```
CallList.Items.Filter = o => 
    predicates.All(predicate => predicate(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: you create a class:

```
class Filter 
{
   public bool ShouldApply {get;set;}
   public Predicate<object> Predicate {get;set;}
}
```

Your view model has a property of type `ICollection<Filter> Filters`. You add all your predicates to this collection.
The checkboxes are data-bound to the corresponding ShouldApply properties.

Your filtering code looks like this:

```
private void applyFiltBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        CallList.Items.Filter = (object item) => return filters.All(f=>f(item)); }
```